# Properly form a generic, RESTful routing scheme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some routes in ASP.NET MVC 3. What I want to achieve is to have the following URLs to be handled correctly:

```
/users
/users/123
/users/123/modules
/users/123/modules/1
/users/123/modules/1/modulesettings
/users/123/modules/1/modulesettings/642
```

I also want to be able to support all the standard HTTP verbs. Now, I have tried creating a few routes in my Global.asax, but there always seems to be one route that doesn't work properly. Here is what I have so far:

```
routes.MapRoute("RESTSubEntity",
            "{entity}/{entityId}/{subEntity}/{subEntityId}/{controller}/{id}/{action}", // action is the associated entity plurality
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { id = @"\d+", entityId = @"\d+", subEntityId = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("RESTEntity",
            "{entity}/{entityId}/{controller}/{id}/{action}", // action is the associated entity plurality
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { id = @"\d+", entityId = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("REST",
            "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { id = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Ugly, I know. I was wondering if there was a way to make all of my routes work with an as generic route as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that you cannot combine a constraint with an optional parameter, which makes perfect sense. Here is the routing scheme I am now using:

```
routes.MapRoute("Resource",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("SubResource",
    "{entityType}/{entityId}/{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { entityId = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("SubSubResource",
    "{entityType}/{entityId}/{subEntity}/{subEntityId}/{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { entityId = @"\d+", subEntityId = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```